# Client Server Java app

Tags: java, ip

I developed a client server based java networking Instant Messaging app. The client program is needed to be run on the client computer whereas the server program is on server computer. This works in my local wi-fi network(Home network). But i want this one to deploy on internet using some servers and so,so that my friend who is in another city can run the client program from there. Would it be possible for me to do this? I tried to learn heroku techniques for java but its hard for me to understand.

Comment: What is your *concrete* problem?

Comment: All you need is a public IP.

Comment: @Tichodroma : When i connect to the internet using my router, the ipv4 address is x.y.z.a,where as,when i use sites like whatismyip to verify my ip,they show a different ip!..I know there must be some configuration issues with the router settings,But if i make somehow the ip address static(which i see from those sites),Could this purpose be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want this one to deploy on internet using some servers and so,so
>   that my friend who is in another city can run the client program from
>   there

You can !

I have two ways:

- 1: You register static ip, so  you can configure you client and
  server program to connect each other.
- 2: Client get current public ip of server(by using some free services:
  email, instant messessing,..), server will auto get current public ip and auto update it's ip(by using some free services), client auto update public ip of server. You can get current public ip of server by [whatismyip](http://www.whatismyip.com/)

Comment: Both the ways seem cool to implement..Thanks..Actually When i connect to the internet using my router, the ipv4 address is x.y.z.a,where as,when i use sites like whatismyip to verify my ip,they show a different ip!..I know there must be some configuration issues with the router settings,But if i make somehow the ip address Static(which i see from those sites),Could this purpose be accomplished?